# Set left padding on div to be 1.5 times it's height without JavaScript?

Tags: css

I have a div of unknown height and width. How can I set the left padding to be 1.5 times it's height?

I need to do this without JavaScript, in other words with CSS only. However the code below shows what I need to achieve if I was using JavaScript:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const height = container.offsetHeight;
const ratio = 1.5;
const paddingLeft = height * ratio;
container.style.paddingLeft = `${paddingLeft}px`;
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.content {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>
      Heading
    </h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v81pu7fk/1/

Comment: and what is the reason? Are you aware if you are able to achieve this, the left padding will keep increasing when you reduce the window size? because the content will make the height growing --> the padding with grow --> the height will grow more --> infinite loop.

Comment: Looks like XY problem.